# Deleting all values from a key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I want to remove all values from a specific key in Python, so for example:

```
dict = {'A': ['1,2', '2,3'], 'B': ['3,4', '5,6']}
new_dict = {'A': ['1,2', '2,3'], 'B': []}
```

So all that's happening in all the values of the key 'B' in this case are being remove.

I've tried iterating over B and removing the values one by one:

```
for i in dict['B']:
    dict['B'].remove(i)
```

But that only seems to remove the first element?

Comment: dict['B'] = [] ?

Comment: Try removing item 1 for each pass, rather than item i.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just doing the following:

```
dict['B'] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just redefine the key as an empty list

```
dict = {'A': ['1,2', '2,3'], 'B': ['3,4', '5,6']}
new_dict = {'A': dict['A'], 'B':[]}
```

Comment: Also see pellucidcoder's response for how to edit your dictionary in-place

Answer (score 0):

If you're removing all the values, then you *know* the result.  Simply do the direct assignment.

```
dict['B'] = []
```

Your attempted `for` loop *seems* valid, but it runs afoul of Python's iteration schema.  When you delete the first element, everything else shifts over one element.  When you go back for the second element -- and the run-time system is referencing the elements by *position* at this point -- there is no such element: `'5,6'` is now the first element, and gets skipped.

You can read about this in any of the postings referring to changing a list while you iterate through it.